# Crystal Reports: How to pass parameter values between subreports?

Tags: crystal-reports

I've been working on a report that makes use of three subreports (A,B and C). The idea here is to locate the subreports side by side, where each one has its own list, but also this:

-A is located on the left (with columns c1, c2 and c3 where c1 is like customerID)

-B is located right after A and has columns (c1, c4 and c6) which should present data corresponding to the records of A according to the same value of c1 (customerID)

-C is located right after B, has the columns (c1, c7 and c8) and the same applies to it as in B.

I want it to look like one single table where c1 should only be visible once.

I also know there is the linking option but it doesn't seem to be working. If that's what you're gonna say, how can I configure the links? If not, how can I do this?

And no, there is no way this could be done in one single report.

Answer (score 1):

To the extent I understand you want to pass the **c1** value across 3 subreports. In this case link the subreports to main reports and pass the `c1` value to the report selection formula of the sub reports so that all reports retrive only c1 value

Now in sub reports B and C .. don't keep C1 column just keep c1 column in sub report A.

```
But let me know any specific reason to use sub reports instead you can place coulms from c1 to 17 side by side in a main report
```

Comment: The reason is that the query (meaning the "data request") is complex enough to justify sliptting it into three parts. If I try to do it on only one report, the results will show up wrong. 

The c1 column is supressed (except for subreport A), it's only there to help see the iterations that the program does.

Comment: does my solution helpful to you?

Comment: It didn't actually solve it, but I managed to find a way out. You did follow my line of thought, but didn't go much further :/

I ended up making a huge report with different sections for each subreport. Time speaks louder right now, so I had to do it like that.